# How to audit changes in OneToMany relationship into owning entity with Spring Data JPA?

Tags: spring-data-jpa

I have successfully set up JPA auditing in an entity. It works fine provided that there is a change in the data of the entity itself. However, the entity contains a @OneToMany collection, and I'd like the owning entity's `@LastModifiedBy` field to also get updated when only the child rows change. I don't want to add auditing fields to each row, if possible.

Definition of relationship in parent:

```
@Entity
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
public class DataHead {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @CreatedBy
    private String creatorUser;

    @CreatedDate
    private Date createdDate;

    @LastModifiedBy
    private String modifierUser;

    @LastModifiedDate
    private Date modifiedDate;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="dataHead", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval=true)
    @Fetch(FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
    @Valid
    private List<DataRow> rows = new AutoPopulatingList<DataRow>(DataRow.class);
    ...
}
```

Tried to add `@EntityListeners` to the child entity, didn't help.

I'm using spring-data-jpa 1.9.4 with Hibernate 4.3.11 as implementation.

Comment: Did you find any workaround ?

Comment: Nope. I have added the auditing fields to the children as well. The upside is that I have row-by-row auditing information now (although I don't really need it).

Comment: Please check my answer here: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58679469/2491098)

Comment: You may try this one: https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-customize-hibernate-dirty-checking-mechanism/

To be honest I did not tried it. For us it is important only in one use case and I don't want to integrate this so we manually update the fields for this one entity.

Answer (score -2):

As workaround, you can try to add additional field to table and annotate it by JPA @Version.

```
@Version
@Column
private int version;
```