# Get original entity triggered the Hibernate Event

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I'm using Spring Boot 2 with JPA 2 on top of Hibernate. I would like to log some auditing information but not only for the actual entity but also about the parent entity.

For example: I have an `Employee` entity that has an `Address` entity. So if the `Address` entity changes I also want to log that the `Employee` was changed. The `Employee` was the entity that was saved even if it is not dirty.

I have found some similar problems:
[Hibernate versioning parent entity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2895460/hibernate-versioning-parent-entity)
This works only if the child entity knows about the parent.

I also found this: https://thoughts-on-java.org/hibernate-tips-increase-version-parent-entity-updating-child-entity/
This solution is a concrete implementation for one case, but I would like a generic solution.

My idea was to find the original entity and if any of it's child entities are dirty then mark the original entity as well.

Answer (score 1):

I had almost the same problem. I wanted the owning entity's "lastModifiedDate" and "Version" fields update when the child entities change. I am using Spring Data JPA Auditing.

I have tested so many things and implemented lots of custom code. Even I was trying to implement a custom dirty check mechanism. I was able to fix parent versioning by following this [blog post](https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-increment-the-parent-entity-version-whenever-a-child-entity-gets-modified-with-jpa-and-hibernate) but nothing worked for auditing.

Finally, Using **Hibernate Bytecode Enhancement Maven plugin** and enabling **DirtyTracking** fixed the issue of both parent versioning and auditing for me. Now the owning entity's "lastModifiedDate" and "version" updates by itself and without any custom code when I edit the child. Bear in mind that I have only tested ManyToOne/OneToMany relation but I think this should work for other relations as well. Also, I am updating the entity from the owning side via JpaRepository (using Spring Data)

To enable Hibernate Bytecode Enhancement, add this plugin to your POM file:

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.hibernate.orm.tooling</groupId>
<artifactId>hibernate-enhance-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>${hibernate.version}</version>
<executions>
    <execution>
        <configuration>
            <failOnError>true</failOnError>
            <enableDirtyTracking>true</enableDirtyTracking>
            <enableAssociationManagement>false</enableAssociationManagement>
            <enableExtendedEnhancement>false</enableExtendedEnhancement>
            <enableLazyInitialization>false</enableLazyInitialization>
        </configuration>
        <phase>compile</phase>
        <goals>
            <goal>enhance</goal>
        </goals>
    </execution>
</executions>
```

Now when you look up the "target" folder, the entities now implement **ManagedEntity and SelfDirtinessTracker** by using SelfDirtinessTracker, the entities keep track of the dirty fields and there's no need for hibernate to check all entities to find dirty ones. This can also improve performance beside fixing the parent auditing and versioning for me. Hope it fixes your problem too.

Answer (score 0):

I tricked the system. Every time I change/remove/add a OneToMany child entity, I call `entity.setLastModifiedDate(myDateProvider.now())`

That makes my parent entity dirty, Hibernate increases the version and I get new, correct lastModifiedDate and lastModifiedBy values from AuditorAware.

It could be a simple, quick and dirty one line solution for this problem.